# Mongoose nested populate with select and limit

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I limit the number of pictures?

`CommentBy` is a ref in `Comment`, which is a ref in `Post`.

```
const posts = await Post.find(filter).populate({
  path: 'comments',
  populate: {
    path: 'commentBy',
    select: 'first_name last_name pictures',
  },
});
```

Post:

```
const postsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    text: String,
    comments: { type: [ObjectId], ref: 'Comment' }, // comment ref here
    reactions: {
      type: [ObjectId],
      ref: 'Reaction',
    },
  },
);
```

Comment:

```
const commentsSchema = new Schema({
  commentBy: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

User:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
  },
  pictures: {
    type: [String],
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that in `mongoose` you can limit a specific field of a populated document.
You could try to use `lean` to return an array of objects and manipulate that in plain JS:

```
let posts = await Post.find(filter).populate({
  path: 'comments',
  populate: {
    path: 'commentBy',
    select: 'first_name last_name pictures',
  },
}).lean().exec();

posts = posts.map((post) => {
    const pics = post.comments.commentBy.pictures 
    if (pics.length <= 10) return post;
    post.comments.commentBy.pictures = pics.slice(0, 10);
    return post;
})
```

Comment: The issue is I need to go one level deeper. This answer only limits commentBy if I'm not mistaken. I wan to limit pictures, which is a property on commentBy.

Comment: @AndyOh Can you show the `Post` schema declaration?

Comment: Sure. It's in OP now.

Comment: @AndyOh Thanks, can you also post the `User` schema?

Comment: Sure. I've added the User schema.